# Creating command: FanceVerb Error, Paragraph ended before

Tags: macros, verbatim

Hi and sorry if that question might be already asked. I try to create a command like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\newcommand{\smallx}[1]{
     \begin{center}
        \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]

            \code{#1}

        \end{Verbatim}
    \end{center}
 }

\begin{document}

    \smallx{tensor.\textbf{vector}(name=None, dtype=config.floatX)}

\end{document}
```

which I hoped I could use like this:

```
\smallx{namespace.\textbf{vector}(name=None, dtype=config.floatX)}
```

to display simple code-like lines with a short command.

Actually it is working. The PDF gets created but I also get those errors:

> FancyVerb Error: ...f{vector}(name=None, dtype=config.floatX)} (followed by: )

and

> Paragraph
>   ended before \FV@BeginScanning was complete. ...f{vector}(name=None)}
>   (followed by: )

and the output looks like this:

[image]

Could anyone explain to me what I need to do to get rid of these errors and make it display just the input of `\smallx{}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi @Jubobs, thanks for the hint. I edited my question.

Comment: You can't have `Verbatim` in the argument to another command. It is not clear what `\code` should do.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I forgot that `\code` is a command too. See my edit.

Comment: Remove the `\begin{Verbatim}` and `\end{Verbatim}` lines. However, boldface won't show, unless you change the monospaced font.

Comment: @egreg Thank you that did it. Do you want to provide the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Verbatim` just to override it; on the other hand, `Verbatim` can't be included in the argument to another command.

Since you mean to use a boldface monospaced font, you also need one that has a boldface variant.

Finally, be more careful with spaces and blank lines in definitions: TeX is not free form  like C, because it's a language aimed to typesetting.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\newcommand{\smallx}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
  \code{#1}
  \end{center}%
 }

\begin{document}

\smallx{tensor.\textbf{vector}(name=None, dtype=config.floatX)}

\end{document}
```

The end-of-lines after `\begin{center}` and `\code{#1}` `\end{center}` need not be masked off, because `center` makes a paragraph.

[image]